# PHP GTK on how to use

Tags: php, desktop-application

I have no knowledge on desktop applications, but I have a project in our school desktop application and only I know is to make websites using php, javascript, css and etc. I heard about **PHP GTK** and I already read many articles and tutorial for windows. But still, I didn't understand on how can I start developing a **PHPGTK** desktop application. I need somebody that will explain to me on how I can install, compile php to .exe to execute it. Or any Idea on how can I make a desktop application that using **PHP**, **MySQL**, **HTML**, **javascript** or any web language except dontnet. I need a browser free for this. I see a application that uses web language and see what he did but I didn't understand. Here is the name of application "**CabalRider**".
 Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Mmm..... are you sure that this is the way to go? Desktop applications would be much easier to build with the tools and languages specialized to do the job. PHP is not really one of them IMO.

Comment: *(reference)* http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/preface.php

Comment: If this desktop application is something that does not require a network connection, then you're on the right track. But think about deployment: you have to install your app on every PC that your application will run on. A browser-accessible app (aka Intranet app) makes more sense in some cases. So assess your needs first.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) you can code programs for Windows, Mac, and Linux using html, css, javascript, and php.